# MooTools Sortables with horizontal list having problems

Tags: mootools, stylesheet, sortables

I am having problems sorting list items using the `Sortables` class when the list items are displayed horizontally. Removing this style fixed everything:

`display: inline`

Created an example on jsfiddle.

This works. Check the stylesheet for `.countries li` - it does not display the list inline - http://jsfiddle.net/Wgpqw/

This does not work properly. I can drag the list items around the list, but the sort randomly happens when moving around - http://jsfiddle.net/Wgpqw/1/

I suspect it has something to do with the list element positioning in inline mode. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Change the styling of `ul` to `display: table` and the `li` elements to `display: table-cell`.

Hacky you say? it works :)

Updated code on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wgpqw/2/